# Preventing a sprite from rotating

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, sprite-kit

I am doing this spritekit game.

I have this object that I want to move up and down when the user touches it. It is an object that has to slide in a rail, up and down or in another case left and right.

So, when the user touches the object I do something like this

```
CGVector force = CGVectorMake(0.0f, 5000.0f);
[object.physicsBody applyForce:force];
```

it is a vertical force applied up.

but when the object collide with others it rotates. Is there a way to prevent the object from rotating?

Comment: nope, it is an object that has to slide in a rail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `object.physicsBody.allowsRotation = NO`. This ignores all angular impulses and forces that would make the body rotate.

Comment: I did that but the object continues to rotate.

Comment: are you sure the object isn't being rotated by something other than just the physics engine? are you setting this property upon the physicsBody creation? does the body have rotational actions attached? if it's in a rail like you said, is it running a followPath SKAction (you can set `orientToPath:NO`, if so)? also, on another note, you should probably be applying an impulse (if it's a one-off kick) rather than force (which is more of a constant idea).